# A Nonabelian group of order of product of primes G has a trivial center - Fraleigh p. 153 15.18

Tags: group-theory, intuition

> Using [Exercise 37](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/688239/53934), show:
>   A nonabelian group G of order pq where p and q are primes has a trivial center.

Reference: http://users.humboldt.edu/pgoetz/Homework%20Solutions/Math%20343/hw`i think 15`solns.pdf

(1.) How do you envisage and envision to prove by contradiction? Why not direct proof?

(2.) What's the intuition?

[image]

Comment: You would think to do it like this precisely due to the previous exercise.

Comment: There is an intuition here that a non-abelian group has to have a non-abelian core (the centre can't be too large), and that the centre can't sit too simply in the group (the quotient by the centre can't be cyclic)

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma:** if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian.

So, only possible order for $G/Z(G)$ is $pq\implies$ $Z(G)=1$