# Explicit representation of $Q_8/Z(Q_8)$,where $Q_8$ is the quaternion group.

Tags: group-theory

I've to prove that $Q_8/Z(Q_8)$ is isomorphic to Klein's $4$-group. I know that 
$Q_8/Z(Q_8)$ has order $4$. But, I'm not able to get the elements of $Q_8/Z(Q_8)$. Please help me in representing $Q_8/Z(Q_8)$ in Roster form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what roster form is, but $1,i,j,k$ is a complete system of coset representatives for $Z(Q_8)=\{\pm 1\}$.

Comment: :thanks for your response,by Roster form we mean  elements of the set are listed within the pair of brackets { } and are separated by commas.
I want all elements of this quotient group to represented explicitly within the pair of brackets { } and are separated by commas.

Comment: Ok, then take the cosets defined by the elements I listed and enclose the list in braces.

Comment: :then elements of this set are {{±1},{±i},{±j},{±k}}.Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to get at it. There is a popular group theory exercise that says [if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is Abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/546971/29335).

You know that $Q_8$ is nonabelian, and that there are only two groups of order $4$ possible...

Comment: :sorry i'm not getting the second line,which 2  groups of order 4 .Please elaborate,it seems interesting..

Comment: :are they Z_4 & klien's 4 group

Comment: @PKStyles yes, those are the only two. If there is no element of order 4, all elements have order 2 or 1.